# How to set auto height in phpexcel?

Tags: php, phpexcel

I am using [phpexcel](http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/) to generate excel document with PHP.

the question is, how to make auto height row using phpexcel?
many thanks :)

Answer (score 74, accepted):

```
$excel->getActiveSheet()->getRowDimension(1)->setRowHeight(-1);
```

Should set the row height to 'auto' for row 1.

Comment: Any idea how to set it for the entire sheet?

Comment: @eddy147 - `foreach($xls->getActiveSheet()->getRowDimensions() as $rd) { 
    $rd->setRowHeight(-1); 
}`

Comment: $excel->getActiveSheet()->getRowDimension( 1 )->setRowHeight( 30 ); working in libreoffice calc.

Answer (score 56):

```
$excel->getActiveSheet()->getDefaultRowDimension()->setRowHeight(-1);
```

Comment: Thanks! That saved me from having to write a loop. :)

Comment: Wow ! It's really what I'm looking for

Comment: @Dhaval Maybe you can help me. Look at this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56469303/how-do-i-make-automatic-height-row-based-on-content-in-the-maatwebsite-version-3

Answer (score 22):

To change height of all rows to auto you can do:

```
foreach($xls->getActiveSheet()->getRowDimensions() as $rd) { 
    $rd->setRowHeight(-1); 
}
```

Comment: Maybe you can help me. Look at this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56469303/how-do-i-make-automatic-height-row-based-on-content-in-the-maatwebsite-version-3

Answer (score 5):

You can set it by using following code,

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getRowDimension(1)->setRowHeight(-1);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('E')->getAlignment()->setWrapText(true);
```